# Using 2 browser at same time causing issue in functionality

Tags: apex, community

I built a Lightning Community component/Page, which takes data from student and creates a case record related to Logged in User's contact in Salesforce.

The user should be able to create the case only once from the Community Page.

It is working fine in the case, I am using one browser at a time.

My code is handling in apex that only insert case if the contact has no case related to it.

Failure Case:

When I am using two browsers simultaneously, two case records are getting created in Salesforce. And in Debug Logs for both apex call. The caseList is coming up as Empty.

Any, idea what should be done to handle such conditions.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: How are you testing "simultaneous" record creation? Are you using some kind of tool here? And are you sure its exactly at the same n-th time period when it hits your logic to verify if a case exists or not? Also having some relevant code here will help someone to assist you.

Comment: Maybe you can check for case records before creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to prevent this is to create a unique field on Case which will get populated based on the user information and those fields based on which case is getting created.

So, only one case will get created and during 2nd case insertion, record will fail to insert because of uniqueness.